# How to fix an error of sorting a hashmap of string as the key, list as the object?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to sort of a `HashMap` that has values of type `List<String>`. I want to sort by the `size()` of each `List`.

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> myCalls = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

I found an example that I changed around to get this.

```
public static <K extends Comparable, V extends Comparable> Map<K, V> sortByValues(Map<K, V> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
            ArrayList myList1 = (ArrayList) o1.getValue();
            ArrayList myList2 = (ArrayList) o2.getValue();

            if (myList1.size() == myList2.size()) {
                return 0;
            } else if (myList1.size() < myList2.size()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });


    Map<K, V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();

    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return sortedMap;
}
```

But when I call like this:

```
sortByValues(myCalls);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(405, 9) java: method sortByValues in class
com.telstra.chronicler.helpers.JsonFileHelper cannot be applied to
given types;   required: java.util.Map<K,V>   found:
java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>  
reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
    bound(s): java.lang.Comparable
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you try `Map<String, List<String>> myCalls = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();`

Comment: `List` does not extend `Comparable`. Also, why are you using raw types? `Comparable` is generic.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is because your method has the generic bound `V extends Comparable` (using a raw type, which should never be done) but the `List` interface does not extend `Comparable`. You appear to have misconceptions about how generics work. In general, you should use the least specific type bounds as inputs and the most specific as outputs. `K` does not need to be `Comparable`. And, when you want to compare something that is not `Comparable`, use a `Comparator`. This is an example of your method implemented in Java 8:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> sortByValues(Map<K, V> map, Comparator<? super V> comparator) {
    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            // sort entries by applying given comparator to values
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue, comparator))
            // collect into a LinkedHashMap using Collectors.toMap
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> {
                // map should never contain duplicate keys
                throw new AssertionError();
            // Collectors.toMap always adds elements in encounter order; using LinkedHashMap here preserves ordering
            }, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

You could call it as follows:

```
sortByValues(myCalls, Comparator.comparing(Collection::size));
```

Comment: What would the equivalent look like in Java 7? You're not wrong on misconceptions. I've never really used generics before.